# NgModel com checkbox no angular

Tags: angular

Tenho uma checkbox que é iterada em um ngfor:

```
 <div *ngFor="let tela of telas; let i = index; trackBy: getIndex" class="custom-control custom-checkbox check">
    <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]=selectedIds[i] (click)="OnCheckboxSelect(tela.id, $event)" #myItem value="{{tela.id}}" id="{{tela.nome_tela}}" name="{{tela.nome_tela}}" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{tela.nome_tela}}">{{tela.nome_tela}}</label>
</div>
```

Tem um momento que eu recebo novamente o array dos selectedIds para realizar alterações, porém recebo o array no seguinte formato:

[1,3,5] São os ids da tela que um usuário pode acessar, porém o meu ngModel precisaria receber: [0:true, 2:true, 4:true] para conseguir bindar.

Estou tentando fazer uma estrutura de repetição pra conseguir o resultado desejado.
Eu tentei algo como:

```
  this.selectedIds = [];
  for(let i=0;i<this.operador.tabela_perm.length;i++){
    this.selectedIds[this.operador.tabela_perm - 1] = true;
  }
```

Mas minha logica ainda está errada. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O `this.operador.tabela_perm` é o array `[1,3,5]`?

Comment: @Renata sim, eu preciso transformar nele no formato em que o ngmodel realiza o bind [chave: true]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estou vendo que você precisa que o valor `true` ou `false` esteja associado ao índice do array, sugiro algo como o código abaixo, assumindo que os valores do `this.operador.tabela_perm` estejam sempre em ordem crescente:

```
let max = this.operador.tabela_perm[this.operador.tabela_perm.length-1];

this.selectedIds = [];
for(let i=0;i<max;i++){
  if(this.operador.tabela_perm.indexOf(i+1)>-1) this.selectedIds[i] = true;
  else this.selectedIds[i] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta com a funcao map do array:

```
this.selectedIds.map(id=>{
   const obj={};
   obj[id-1]=true;
   return obj;
})
```

Comment: Não funcionou pra mim. Eu sinceramente não sei qual condição eu devo usar pra checar ou não a checkbox com base no que recebo do meu backend. Eu recebo um array[1,3,5] que é a permissão das telas. pensei em fazer algo como [checked]=selectedId[i] == tela.id mas não deu certo.